# My wordpress isnt coming up after I put it into my ftp client

Tags: wordpress, ftp, filezilla, bluehost

So i have uploaded my unzipped wordpress files onto my filezilla ftp client and put them in a folder. But when I check the domain.com/wordpressfolder I keep getting a 404 this url does not exist on the server. Not sure what im doing wrong because there were no failed transfer when uploading onto my ftp. Could I have done something wrong on the hosting server side(bluehost) or should that not matter?

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you need to do is download **WordPress** zip. Unzip files and open **wordpress** folder. After that select all and transfer them into root directory. When all files will be uploaded, open [Tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) and go through it.

Comment: That's what I did expect the tutorial i use told me to take all the the files that where on the ftp client and put them in an folder and call it old so I always have them if I need them. It then told me to make a new folder and drop the unzipped wordpress stuff in there. But when I visit my url/theworpressfoldername the tutorial isnt coming up. it justs says cant be found. Im really new at web development so thats why im having some trouble with this

Comment: You don't need to make additional folders. I will show you and example I hope you will understand. For example:
I open my FileZilla and go to directory called _public_html_, after that I open WP zip file and unzip em to the desktop, so now I have new 1 folder on my desktop called **wordpress**. Now it's time to open this wordpress folder select and copy all files and paste them to the public_html (or where is your root directory is). When all files would be transferred open **domain.com/wp-admin/install.php** and go through installation.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the file you are uploading is a theme file or a complete wordpress file. If it is a theme file, you need to activate it in the admin panel. If it is complete wordpress file, please make sure that you are uploading it to the right location.